# CUPS only prints blank pages

Tags: printing

I have an apple laserwriter 16/600 printer.

Everything worked fine in ubuntu 10.04.

When I upgraded to 14.04, the printer started printing the correct number of pages but all blank, no toner on them.

After a fresh install of 15.04, the problem remains.

I've tried both LPT and networked printing. Same result.

This is my cups log after a test page printing job.

```
# tail -f /var/log/cups/error_log
I [17/Sep/2015:15:44:36 +0200] Saving job.cache...
I [17/Sep/2015:15:44:36 +0200] Saving subscriptions.conf...
D [17/Sep/2015:15:44:37 +0200] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not    busy",busy="Dirty files"
D [17/Sep/2015:15:44:37 +0200] Report: clients=5
D [17/Sep/2015:15:44:37 +0200] Report: jobs=2
D [17/Sep/2015:15:44:37 +0200] Report: jobs-active=0
D [17/Sep/2015:15:44:37 +0200] Report: printers=1
D [17/Sep/2015:15:44:37 +0200] Report: stringpool-string-count=7571
D [17/Sep/2015:15:44:37 +0200] Report: stringpool-alloc-bytes=11392
D [17/Sep/2015:15:44:37 +0200] Report: stringpool-total-bytes=166880
D [17/Sep/2015:15:49:07 +0200] cupsdAddCert: Adding certificate for PID 0
D [17/Sep/2015:15:49:07 +0200] Closing client 5 after 300 seconds of inactivity.
D [17/Sep/2015:15:49:07 +0200] [Client 5] Closing connection.
D [17/Sep/2015:15:49:07 +0200] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not busy", busy="Not busy"
D [17/Sep/2015:15:49:07 +0200] Closing client 8 after 300 seconds of inactivity.
D [17/Sep/2015:15:49:07 +0200] [Client 8] Closing connection.
D [17/Sep/2015:15:49:07 +0200] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Not busy", busy="Not busy"
D [17/Sep/2015:15:49:07 +0200] Report: jobs=2
D [17/Sep/2015:15:49:07 +0200] Report: jobs-active=0
D [17/Sep/2015:15:49:07 +0200] Report: printers=1
D [17/Sep/2015:15:49:07 +0200] Report: stringpool-string-count=7569
D [17/Sep/2015:15:49:07 +0200] Report: stringpool-alloc-bytes=11392
D [17/Sep/2015:15:49:07 +0200] Report: stringpool-total-bytes=166832
```

Can someone point me in the right direction or suggest further ways to troubleshoot CUPS?

Or maybe a way to downgrade to the 10.04 cups version (1.4.3) which I know to work? Dependencies hell, I guess?

Thanks!